# SpaCy's Matcher Regular Expression not matching string

Tags: python, spacy

I have the following code and regular expresion specified in my pattern. I am trying to get SpaCy to match **24.51c/kWh** However the matched text returned is **24.51c**

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "[0-9]+[,.]?[0-9]+[Cc/KWHkwh]+"}}]
matcher.add("Usage", None, pattern)
doc = nlp(u"Peak Usage 409 24.51c/kWh $100.25")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

[image]

Using this regular expression works in other editors

[image]

I cannot find any SpaCy specific tester online for regular expressions. Is there something that I am missing? Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think the issue is the '/' in the text that is throwing it. Just need to see how I can espace is. If I replace the '/' with '//' it finds a match.

Comment: How is `Matcher` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Have updated the code to show the Matcher import.

Comment: SpaCy uses the regular `re` library. Your text is tokenized in a such a way that `/` is separated into a different  token, `24.51c/kWh` is split into `24.51c`, `/` and `kWh`.

Comment: Add regex in tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SpaCy uses the regular `re` library. Your text is tokenized in a such a way that `/` is separated into a different  token, `24.51c/kWh` is split into `24.51c`, `/` and `kWh`.

To correctly match the string you need you may use

```
pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "(?i)[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?[ckwh]+"}}, 
           {'ORTH': '/'}, {"LOWER": {"REGEX": "(?i)^[ckwh]+$"}}]
matcher.add("Usage", None, pattern)
```

Or

```
pattern = [{'ENT_TYPE': 'CARDINAL'}, 
       {'ORTH': '/'}, {"LOWER": {"REGEX": "(?i)^[lckwh]+$"}}]
```

where `{'ENT_TYPE': 'CARDINAL'}` matches [*"numerals that do not fall under another type."*](https://spacy.io/api/annotation)

Full snippet:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "(?i)[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?[ckwh]+"}}, 
           {'ORTH': '/'}, {"LOWER": {"REGEX": "(?i)^[ckwh]+$"}}]
matcher.add("Usage", None, pattern)
doc = nlp("Peak Usage 409 24.51c/kWh $100.25")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

Output:

```
17478281289916104085 Usage 3 6 24.51c/kWh
```

So, `(?i)[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?[ckwh]+` matches 1+ digits, then an optional sequence of a dot or comma and then 1+ digits, and then 1+ `c`, `k`, `w` or `h` letters in a case insensitive way. Then a `/` token should follow. Then, a token that is equal to `c`, `k`, `w` or `h` (case insensitively), too.